# ParserError: Expected identifier but got '=' ;

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm a beginner of solidity. I just create uint abc array and declare a public variable layercount and want to assign initial value of this. However, the error code as the topic is prompt up.

So, how can I assign initial value to the variable?
And please tell me why what I did is wrong.

````
contract class21{

    uint [12] public abc;

    uint256 public layercount;

    layercount = 0;

  
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this

```
contract Class21 {
  uint[12] public abc;
  uint256 public layerCount = 0;
}
```

always assign the inital value like that. Later if you want to change that value make a function that sets it to be what you want

Comment: welcome to solidity :) Contracts and libraries should be named using the CapWords style /  
Declarations of array variables should not have a space between the type and the brackets. https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/style-guide.html